# Socket IO websockets issues

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I have a node express webserver starting up on my debian linux box on port 8080-8083 using pm2 cluster.
I have an nginx reverse proxy server setup on the server to redirect correctly to the node-express server, with the following `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name a.registered.dns.domain.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name a.registered.dns.domain.com;
        ssl_certificate /home/admin/certs/a.registered.dns.domain.com.chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/certs/a.registered.dns.domain.com.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                proxy_pass http://nodes;
        }

        location /socket.io {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;

                proxy_pass http://nodes;

                # enable WebSockets
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

upstream nodes {
        # enable sticky session based on IP
        ip_hash;

        server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=20s;
        server 127.0.0.1:8081 fail_timeout=20s;
        server 127.0.0.1:8082 fail_timeout=20s;
        server 127.0.0.1:8083 fail_timeout=20s;
}
```

This creates the websocket just fine between the server and the client as seen here. [image: chrome network]

upgrades the connection from the long polling to the websocket with the status 101.  If I do something from the site that sends an emit over the socket, the server receives it and acts on it appropriately. So Far So Good.

However, if I do something elsewhere that causes the server to emit out to the client, I can see using `DEBUG='socket.io*' pm2 restart http-server --update-env` on the server that the socket information is received and emitted out, the client never receives the data packet it should.  can confirm this by running `localStorage.debug = '*';` from the console in my chrome dev tools.

Saw the emit out and nothing but ping and pong packets on the websocket.

This all works correctly if I open ports 8080-8083 and use only an http connection. So it feels as if there is some issue with the nginx reverse proxy for the ssl connection of my site.

Comment: Are you using sticky load balancing?  Socket.io starts a connection with a couple http requests and those need to get load balanced to the same server in your cluster for the socket.io connection to work properly.

Comment: Yeah, I am. based on the upstream nodes and ip_hash

Comment: What are you using on the server to make sure that your emit gets forwarded to the host that actually has the socket.io connection?  Are you using socket.io-redis?

Comment: ip_hash makes them sticky so everything from the same IP address gets sent to the same node. Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: Are you only ever doing `.emit()` on the server from the node that is the one that has the socket.io connection?  What if another server wants to emit to that client?